# DirectTV black out the screen and says “Your network conditions may be degrading your video stream.”

Tags: networking

While watching DirectTV NOW programs, the screen will go black with a note that says:

> "Your network conditions may be degrading your video stream. Please check that your network's settings, signal, and equipment location are optimal for a solid internet condition."

If this problem is the fault of my network condition, where should I go to check it and correct it?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Is your connection wired or wireless?

Comment: My guess would be it’s detecting a slow download speed. What’s your download speed you pay for?

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, this is an Internet video streaming service. What the message most likely means is a slow connection from a) the device you're watching on, to b) their server.

This can be because your device is not well connected to your home Internet router, your router has a slow Internet connection or you are overloading your Internet connection with other things (e.g. file uploads), or their systems are overloaded. You can individually troubleshoot all but their system being overloaded.

For example, you can try using a wired connection to your home Internet router.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to wait until somebody fix things on their side.

Their service is built very poorly. I had similar issues with them more than one time.

I have a business class fiber optic connection and no, there's no problem with my connection (I would be out of business if I had a connection issue).

This is 2019 and they could have at least a tool to send them all the errors their player generates on the javascript console. I use sentry.io, and I'm sure they can afford something as good or even better.

Their player spits out the error message

`Error obtaining certificate at url https://www.directvnow.com/wv/cert_license_widevine_com.bin.`

on the console (among many other error messages), which I suspect that is what triggers the error "Your network conditions may be degrading your video stream.".

I also suggest that you don't waste your time trying to reach to them through support.

A company as big as theirs, should have a dashboard showing when this happens so they can act right away. But it looks like the whole thing is developed by some third party / second rate consultancy that will act only next day.